# How --fail-at-end works in maven?

Tags: maven

I have a master pom which build multiple modules. These modules also have multiple modules within themselves. These modules are interdependent on each other. When I build the system using `mvn -T 4 clean install -DskipTests` code, build always fails.

But when I use `mvn -T 4 --fail-at-end clean install -DskipTests` there is no error and the build is successful without errors.
As per my understanding --fail-at-end simply continues execution if there is some error and reports them at the end.
But is is behaving in a different way here.
How is this possible and what behaviour is being displayed here?

**Edit**-

Scenario-
It fails and says that it is not able to find the dependencies.

Example-
3 modules are there

- Mod1
- Mod2
- Mod3

and Mod3 is dependent on Mod2.
If we start in multithreaded mode and let's say there are 2 threads. One of them starts building Mod1 and other starts building Mod3 then it fails and says that "It is not able to resolve dependency Mod2" which is required by Mod3.

But if I build it with **--fail-at-end then** it works fine. I don't know how it is working, whether it waits and tries after dependencies are built or uses older version of builds or something else.

Comment: If adding `--fail-at-end` makes the build succeed when it should otherwise fail, there's a bug somewhere. Can you post more of your set-up? What fails and why?

Comment: @Tunaki - i have updated question with a scenario. Please have a look.

Comment: It seems your dependencies are not correctly resolved. This could happen for example by depending on classifier artifacts from other modules. That way, maven itself does not know about the dependency and tries to build in the wrong order. So this should be fixed first (if your setup is complex, a dependency on the pom of mod2 should do it as workaroung). As to why the build succeed with --fail-at-end: Might it be just a result of subsequent runs? If you build with --fail-at-end the first time, mod2 will be in the local rep and the next build will succeed. (continued)

Comment: Please try cleaning your local repository before each run to make sure that we are not following the wrong track. Also, I assume without multithreading, everything works?

Comment: @blackbuild - i have tried after cleaning local repo. It is working fine with --fail-at-end.

Comment: Ok, so since that's rule out. Can you post (part of) your poms? What are the types of the modules and how are the dependencies defined? Are you using classifiers?

Comment: No, actually I can't use actual pom's content here. These are linked using simple parent tags and modules tag.